# How can I loop this decision structure?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, structure

Sorry I'm having a hard time getting this loop and I though I'd stop tweaking it and ask SO. I want the decision structure to loop, I want it to stop looping by inputting "4", and I want the "Make a selection" prompt to print each time. Thanks!

```
public class HW1Geo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This program was created in order to allow the user to calculate the areas of rectangles, triangles, and circles.

        System.out.println("Thank you for using the MCCH GeoCal program. \nWith this program, you will be able to find the area of three kinds of shapes.\nThis program uses doubles.");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please make a selection:");
        System.out.println("1 - Area of a rectangle");
        System.out.println("2 - Area of a triangle");
        System.out.println("3 - Area of a circle");
        System.out.println("4 - End program");
        int select = keyboard.nextInt();

        // This decision structure with a nested loop will allow the user to continue to make selections until they decide to quite the program.

        while(select != 4) {

            if(select == 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter the length of the rectangle.");
                double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter the width of the rectangle");
                double width = keyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is: " + rectArea(length, width));
                break;
            }
            else if(select == 2) {
                System.out.println("Enter the height of the triangle.");
                double height = keyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter the size of the base of the triangle.");
                double base = keyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The area of the triangle is: " + triArea(height, base));
                break;
            }
            else if(select == 3) {
                System.out.println("Enter the radius of the circle.");
                double radius = keyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The area of the circle is: " + cirArea(radius));
                break;
            }
            else if(select != 1 && select != 2 && select != 3 && select != 4) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect input.");
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for using this program.");
    }

    // This method is used to find the area of a rectangle.
    public static double rectArea(double length, double width) {
        double area = length * width;
        return area;    
    }
    public static double triArea(double height, double base) {
        double area = 0.5 * base * height;
        return area;
    }
    public static double cirArea(double radius) {
        double area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        return area;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just move the prompt (menu) code lines and the `select = keyboard.nextInt();` line **into** the top of **while** loop above the first **if** statement. Above the loop have: `int select;`. Remove the `int` type declaration from the `int select = keyboard.nextInt();` line.

Comment: Also.... remove the `break;` statement from all **if** statement code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use do-while
syntax
do {wirte code here}
while (condition)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the update of the `select`, I mean, the lack of update on it.

You can use a `do-while` instead of `while`, here's a modified version of your code:

```java
public class Main {
        public static void main(String... args) {

            System.out.println("Thank you for using the MCCH GeoCal program. \nWith this program, you will be able to find the area of three kinds of shapes.\nThis program uses doubles.");
            System.out.println();

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            int select = 0;

            do {
                System.out.println("Please make a selection:");
                System.out.println("1 - Area of a rectangle");
                System.out.println("2 - Area of a triangle");
                System.out.println("3 - Area of a circle");
                System.out.println("4 - End program");

                select = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (select == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the length of the rectangle.");
                    double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter the width of the rectangle");
                    double width = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is: " + rectArea(length, width));
                } else if (select == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the height of the triangle.");
                    double height = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter the size of the base of the triangle.");
                    double base = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("The area of the triangle is: " + triArea(height, base));
                } else if (select == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the radius of the circle.");
                    double radius = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("The area of the circle is: " + cirArea(radius));
                } else if (select < 1 || select > 4) {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect input.");
                }

            } while (select != 4);
            System.out.println("Thank you for using this program.");
        }

        // This method is used to find the area of a rectangle.
        private static double rectArea(double length, double width) {
            return length * width;
        }

        private static double triArea(double height, double base) {
            return 0.5 * base * height;
        }

        private static double cirArea(double radius) {
            return Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `You can use a do-while instead of while` ... Why? What is wrong with using the **while** loop?

Comment: It’s not wrong, it’s just a matter of the way you think/write your logic. In your use-case you do need to repeat a specific part of the program while the input is not 4, if you use do-while you write less code and the first execution needs to happen anyway

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying the way you've done it is wrong. There is nothing wrong with it but then again there is nothing wrong with using a **while** loop as the original code was written. Also, you will have to show me how writing `do { ... } while (...);` is less code than writing `while (...) { ... }`.

Comment: I never said there’s something wrong by using while, and it’s a matter of logic. The block inside the loop needs to execute every time until the input is 4. If while is used you need to receive the input before the loop and also in the end of it, while using do-while you only need to add it in the loop itself. Simple as that.